# Why do shockwaves refract when they travel into the ground?

Tags: refraction, non-linear-systems, shock-waves

If a shockwave from something like an explosion travels into the ground, why will it refract? The speed of sound is far different in the ground, but what would make it refract? I can’t seem to find anything on this.

[image]

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/808403/2451

Comment: Because the speed of sound is different. Transmission/reflection coefficients are all about changes in wave propagation conditions.